# How can I specify "any character" including double quotes, gt, lt, equal

Tags: php, regex

In php I have next text:

```
$text='<div id="my_date_div"
                            year="2010"
                            month="12"
                            day="07"
                            hour="00"
                            minute="00"
                        >
                  <span id="my_span_days">dys</span>
                            <span id="my_span_hours">hrs</span>
                                                 </div>'
```

I would like to perform a preg_replace() to keep only certain values of the upper text, for example year (2010) and hour(00).

I perform a lookup for /year=\"/ and for /hour=\"/, however I dont know how to remove the other text which I dont want since the expresion [.+\s+]* does not match characters like " or <

What I have is

```
$regex = "/[.+\s+]*year=\"(\d+)\"[.+\s+]*hour=\"(\d+)\"[.+\s+]*$/";
$regrep = "$1 $2";
echo preg_replace($regex, $regrep, $text);
```

Any hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to match the text you want and replace the input string with the matched part:

```
preg_match_all('/((?:year|hour)\s*=\s*"\d+")/m',$text,$m);
$text = implode("\n",$m[1]);
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/A2yMs)

Answer (score 1):

.+\s+ inside [] represent themselves, they have no special meaning. Thats why they don't match to " <.
codaddict's answer has also one good property: order of hour year attributes in source text isn't meaningful.

Comment: `\s` is still `\s` inside `[]`.